# Suggest a data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

There are **'u' number of unique users.**

There are **'w' number of different web pages and there are 'p' number of products.**

Based on current user and current web page, i want to advertise appropriate product in that page for that user.

Which data structure will be good for this requirement.

I am thinking about

`HashMap (User,HashMap(WebPage,Product))`

Or

`HashMap(WebPage,HashMap(User,Product))`

Which Object has to be key for outer HashMap.

Will sizes of Users, WebPages have any impact here?

Any other appropriate data structure for this situation?

Thank You

Comment: What you describe sounds more like `Map<Pair<User,WebPage>, Set<Product>>` to me. Regarding to other question, order in which you query this map will likely not matter, since you'll always have to query two times, one with user and then with WebPage. Relative performance will depend on number of hash collisions between your users and pages. Overall I would expect that this is either subjective, or you did not provide enough information to make an educated decision.

Comment: Map<Pair<User,WebPage>, Set<Product>>. If we use Pair<User,WebPage> then there will be u*w keys. Which is very huge. Will it have any impact on HashMap performance?

Comment: Isn't there some information missing? Like the relationships between users, pages, and products? How do you know what products are appropriate to display to a user? How do you know if a product is appropriate for a Web page? You haven't given given us enough information to provide a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use something like this;

`HashMap(User+WebPage,List<Product>)` where `User+WebPage` can be an object with user & page fields, or some other unique identifier for user&page combination.

Comment: Assume we are using User+WebPage as key and Product as value. Then there should be u*w keys in the HashMap. Storing huge number of (key,value) pairs will degrade the performance of HashMap.

Comment: if number of users and number of web pages are n, then if we take HashMap(User+WebPage, Product) then we should have n*n key value pairs.

Comment: @Krishna lol you are right, sorry. But the thing is, you cannot degrade the performance of the HashMap, don't you know how it is implemented? get complexity is always 1

Comment: I am thinking about the performance degradation while rehashing. In first case, we are using multiple small hash maps (1 outer hash map and many inner hash maps). In second case we are using one big hash map. In second case, will rehashing will be a problem? Can it get such big contiguous memory location for bucket array?

Comment: @Krishna what are the objects that are in this dataStructure? If you use some identifiers for them, you would never reach that high amount of memory & performance troubles.

Comment: My main intention is to know if we have a situation to decide a value based on a combination of 2 objects, which approach is better. Single hashmap(obj1+obj2, value) or hashmap(obj1,hashmap(obj2,value)). Thank you for answer and nice discussion

Comment: @Krishna I understand but it depends, are you constantly going to be using this HashMap? It is not nice to keep your data (a sizable one) in a variable in your running application. If you worry about such performance & memory issues with storing this data, why not store it in some sort of DB, or some NoSQL db, maybe

Comment: Yes. When it is growing, It has to be stored in DB.